# Rails Tutorial 3 Chapter 8: Sign up - Validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to get an error box to appear on my sign up page when the information has been entered incorrectly, however for some reason it comes up with a Template is missing error.

here is the full error message

```
Missing template users/create, application/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/chris/rails/demo_app/app/views"
```

It looks like it's trying to create a new file inside application called create but I'm not really sure why it's doing that?

here is my users_controller.rb

```
def new
 @user = User.new
 @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
  redirect_to @user
 else
  @title = "Sign up"
  render = 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

Here's my _error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not really sure what other files to list so if I have missed anything important please let me know!

Thanks :)

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render is a function, not an variable, so you don't want to say  `render = 'new'`, you want to pass the string 'new' into the render function, so  `render 'new'` should work just fine.  This is the hard thing about learning Ruby, the lack of parentheses sometimes confuses people about variables and functions.

Comment: Bingo! Urgh it's always the small things I keep getting tripped up on, thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
render = 'new'
```

try to use:

```
 render :action => 'new'
```